# windows is not responding in face detection using python and open CV

Tags: python, opencv

The problem i faced is the that window opens but is not responding. I am using pycharm IDE for the development of the code. When I debugged the code i found that the statements in for loop are not executed and code recursively moves to while true condition only comes up to for loop and then again to the while true condition.
 The code is  as below :
  import cv2
    import numpy as np

```
face_detect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
recognizer=cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
recognizer.load("Training/trainingdataset.yml")
id=0
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
while True:
ret,image = cam.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
faces=face_detect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    id,conf=recognizer.predict(gray[x:x+w,y:y+h])
    cv2.putText(image, str(id), (x,y+h) , font , 1 ,(0,255,0))
    cv2.imshow("facedetector",image)
```

Comment: `imshow` with no `waitKey`. Read [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow): "This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image." | Wow, if I had a dollar for each time this is asked...

Comment: thank you so much...it worked....